# Is there an angle $\alpha$ that makes both $\cos \alpha$ and $\sin\alpha$ rational?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, trigonometry, rational-numbers

This may be a duplicate, but I couldn't find it yet.

My attempt is to write $\cos\alpha = p/q$ and $\sin\alpha = j/k$, where $p,q,j,k \in \mathbb Z$ and $|p|\le|q|,\ |j|\le|k|$, then
$$
\frac{p^2}{q^2} + \frac{j^2}{k^2}  = 1 \implies k^2p^2+q^2j^2 = q^2k^2
$$
and the question becomes are there any integrers that satisfy the last equation. But to procede it may require some knowledge in number theory which I lack.

Comment: Trivially you can set $\alpha=k\cdot(\pi/2)$ for any integer $k$.

Comment: $\alpha=n\pi/2, n\in\Bbb Z$ works.

Comment: There are trivial solutions at multiples of $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: I should have written except that silly, I mean trivial case

Comment: Take also a look at Niven’s theorem: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem

Comment: @Yalikesifulei Thanks, but I do not restrict the angle to rational values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, any angle of a Pythagorean triangle satisfies this. For example, there is a 3-4-5 triangle; one of its acute angles satisfies $\cos \alpha=4/5$ and $\sin \alpha=3/5$.

Comment: @Physor Yes, it would have to be, because you can clear the denominators of the sine and cosine functions applied to one of the angles, and you are left with a right triangle with each side a positive integer.You can also construct *minor variations* of such triangles (i.e. where one of the angles is $~ > 90^{\circ}$) so that one of the corresponding functions (either sine or cosine) is negative.

Answer (score 3):

To add to @EspeciallyLime's answer a general example, consider $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ which are non zero such that
$$ \sin(\alpha) = \frac{m^2-n^2}{m^2 + n^2}$$ and $$\cos(\alpha) = \frac{2mn}{m^2+n^2} $$ and it is easy to check that denominators and numerators satisfy required properties.